# Generating function of $t[n,k]=t[n-2,k]-t[n-2,k-1]- \frac{n^2-4n+3}{4}t[n-2,k-2]$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm having trouble finding the generating function

$F(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t(n,k)x^n y^k$

of the sequence that satisfies $t[n,k]=t[n-2,k]-t[n-2,k-1]- \frac{n^2-4n+3}{4}t[n-2,k-2]\;\text{for}\; n,k\geq 3$ such that
$t(1,1)=1$ and $t(2,1)=1$ and $t(2,1)=-1/2$ and $t(n,k)=0$ for any negative $n,k$ or if $k>n$.

I got $F(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{1-x^2(1-y-(n^2-4n+3)/4 * y^2)}$ which, when expanding with Wolfram, does not match the coefficients. Any help?

I'm also not sure if $F(x,y)$ should be defined as it is, or if, given our recursion, i should use exponential gen function or a mix.

Comment: Do you also want to use $F(x,y)$ (or an exponential generating function) to solve for $t[n,k]$, or do you just need an explicit form for $F(x,y)$?

Comment: I need an explicit form of $t[n,k]$.

Comment: "I got" Perhaps you should show *how* you got this, which will enable others to trouble-shoot and give feedback.